# How to exclude a library from the eclipse default test classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an interesting problem. I have two projects, which both depend on different versions of a library. The individual projects cannot change their dependencies, due to version constraints.

So:

Project A depends on lib version 1

Project B depends on lib version 2

lib version 2 is binary compatible with version 1, but has additional functionality so we don't want to update project A to depend on version2.

When running tests that only involve project A, then the class path is perfect, it only contains version 1 of lib.

When running tests that only involve project B, then the class path is perfect, it only contains version 2 of lib.

When running tests that involve both projects A and B, then the class path is broken, as it contains both version 1 and 2 of lib.

Is there any way to say "use this library for compiling only, and don't export for the runtime class path"? This is in some ways related (but opposite) to the exported flag on a JAR file, since that exports it to projects that you depend on as a compile dependency. I want to *not* export it as a runtime dependency.

When running from the command line this all works fine for us, it is only within Eclipse that we are seeing this problem.

Comment: In Eclipse, under File > Properties >Java Build Path, I think you can select the libraries for compile-time in the 'Libraries' Tab, and the libraries for run-time in the 'Order and Export' Tab

Comment: @lshnark yes, but there is no way to remove an entry from the ‘order and export’ tab… if I could do that I would be a happy camper!

Comment: How about using classpath variables? http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-classpath-variables.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify a classpath for a junit launch configuration via the junit run configuration dialog. See here section "Customizing a Test Configuration": https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm

[image: junit run configuration dialog]
(image from https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm)

The new version of the library needs to be added to the classpath before the default element so that during class loading the new library version will be seen first.

After you have configured the correct classpath export the launch configuration to the workspace via `Export ... -> Launch Configurations`. Then you will be able to run it with right clicking on it and selecting `Run as -> <Your Lauch Config name>`

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned, I am hoping to avoid this, since the default class path is *big* (100 plus entries), and is _almost_ correct, this is the only duplicate library with different versions that we have in the system.

Comment: But then can't you just use the normal project classpath there and add a single user entry for that library, which is before that project classpath? Than class shadowing should do its job. Or is it a problem if the other version is only on the classpath?

Comment: ^ Since version 2 is binary compatible with version 1, and project A depends on version 1 already, if you replace version 1 with version 2 instead, it's not like project A will be using the additional functionality that version 2 provides. (Yes, in the future, people making changes to project A can use those features, but right now, no one depends on them). If that's the case why not just only use version 2?

Comment: @lshnark Good question! The issue is that the lib is backwards binary compatible, but not forwards binary compatible. That is all methods in version 1 exist in version 2, but version 2 has additional overloads that means compiling against version 2 does not give you a binary that runs against version 1! Painful! However, your hint about just explicitly adding only version 2 of lib as an explicit dependency before the defaults appears to have solved the issue. If no other better answers come up, I'll accept your answer, for the hint in the comment.

Comment: @PaulWagland Which explicit hint in the comment are you referring to? I would like to add that to my answer or you may suggest an edit or write that in an answer yourself. But for the specific problem you seem to have my answer at least as it currently stands doesn't seem to solve it completely.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker the specific hint is putting the explicit dependency earlier in the list, this prevents half of it getting pulled from the old library, and half from the new lib…